# How to build an C++ app using Ray C++ API using a build system other than Bazel?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, ray

I've found this information at https://www.anyscale.com/blog/modern-distributed-c-with-ray. I'm wondering if anyone already tried to build a C++ app to call Ray C++ API and link Ray libraries, using a build system like cmake or make other than Bazel? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: What’s the issue with Bazel?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Bazel is not an issue to me, but the main codebase created by someone else already uses Cmake.

Comment: hi @3rdgenta! Can you link to this question in the [Ray Discuss](https://discuss.ray.io/) or [Ray Slack channel](https://www.ray.io/community)? It's a good way to get traction to your StackOverflow question as the Ray folks monitor those sites!

Answer (score 0):

I link directly to the ray_api library using:

```
g++ ray_test.cpp  -O0 -I/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/cpp/include -L/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/cpp/lib -lray_api -g -std=c++17
```

use "ray cpp --show-library-path" to find where is the ray-cpp install.

But here's a trickier question, when use the "Put" function will get std::bad_alloc.

```
auto object = ray::Put(100);
```